# Triggering CSS filter from outside Div

Tags: css, filtering, containers

working on implementing this content filtering system that is pure CSS but am open to implementing jquery or js to make this function more cleanly. Currently there is a div that slides in from the side of the page. Ideally, this div will have controls to filter the content on the page. The filtering function I've found seems to only work when both the labels and the tiles are in the same container. 
I want to use links inside of this div to trigger the same filtering events. I hope that this is clear; basically I want all of those label links to be inside of the slideout div "#menu"; if possible to replace the ones on the body of the page completely.

I apologize in advance for my cluelessness. Thanks!

css:

```
#menu {
top: 60px;
text-align: center;
height: 500px;
position: fixed;
width: 300px;
right: -300px;
{

   .container {
  padding-top: 60px;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="radio"] {
display:none;
}
label {
  width:12%;
  text-align:center;
  color:#222222;
  padding:0.5%;
  margin:0.5%;
  margin-bottom:30px;
 cursor:pointer;
}
input[type="radio"][id="blue"]:checked + label {color:#6666ff;
}
input[type="radio"][id="blue"]:checked ~ .red, input[type="radio"][id="blue"]:checked ~ .green, input[type="radio"][id="blue"]:checked ~ .yellow {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  opacity:0;
}
input[type="radio"][id="red"]:checked + label {color:#ff4466;
}
input[type="radio"][id="red"]:checked ~ .blue, input[type="radio"][id="red"]:checked ~ .green, input[type="radio"][id="red"]:checked ~ .yellow {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  opacity:0;
}
input[type="radio"][id="green"]:checked + label {color:green;
}
input[type="radio"][id="green"]:checked ~ .blue, input[type="radio"][id="green"]:checked ~ .red, input[type="radio"][id="green"]:checked ~ .yellow {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  opacity:0;
}

input[type="radio"][id="yellow"]:checked + label {
  color:yellow;
}
input[type="radio"][id="yellow"]:checked ~ .blue, input[type="radio"][id="yellow"]:checked ~ .red, input[type="radio"][id="yellow"]:checked ~ .green {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  opacity:0;
}

input[type="radio"][id="toby"]:checked + label {color:purple;
}
input[type="radio"][id="toby"]:checked ~ .marda {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  opacity:0;
}

input[type="radio"][id="marda"]:checked + label {color:orange;
}
input[type="radio"][id="marda"]:checked ~ .toby {
  width:0;
  height:0;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  opacity:0;
}

.tile {
  width:23%;
  height:100px;
  float:left;
  transition:all 1s;
  margin:0.5%;
  padding:0.5%;
}
.green {
  background:#66dd99;
}
.blue {
  background:#6666ff;
}
.red {
  background:#ff4466;
}
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
.marda {
}
.toby {
}
```

html:

```
<div id="menu">
blue red green yellow marda toby reset
</div>
<div class="container"> 
  <input type="radio" id="blue" name="color" />
  <label for="blue">BLUE</label>
  <input type="radio" id="red" name="color"/>
  <label for="red">RED</label>
  <input type="radio" id="green" name="color"/>
  <label for="green">GREEN</label>
  <input type="radio" id="yellow" name="color"/>
  <label for="yellow">YELLOW</label>
  <input type="radio" id="marda" name="color"/>
  <label for="marda">MARDA</label>
  <input type="radio" id="toby" name="color"/>
  <label for="toby">TOBY</label>
  <input type="radio" id="reset" name="color"/>
  <label for="reset">RESET</label><br><br>

  <div class="tile blue marda">1</div>
  <div class="tile green toby">2</div>
  <div class="tile blue toby">3</div>
  <div class="tile green toby">4</div>
  <div class="tile blue toby">5</div>
  <div class="tile red toby">6</div>
  <div class="tile red marda">7</div>
  <div class="tile green marda">8</div>
  <div class="tile blue marda">9</div>
  <div class="tile green marda">10</div>
  <div class="tile red marda">11</div>
  <div class="tile green marda">12</div>
  <div class="tile blue marda">13</div>
  <div class="tile blue toby">14</div>
  <div class="tile green toby">15</div>
  <div class="tile red marda">16</div>
  <div class="tile blue toby">1</div>
  <div class="tile red marda">2</div>
  <div class="tile blue marda">3</div>
  <div class="tile green toby">4</div>
  <div class="tile blue marda">5</div>
  <div class="tile red marda">6</div>
  <div class="tile red marda">7</div>
  <div class="tile green toby">8</div>
  <div class="tile blue marda">9</div>
  <div class="tile green toby">10</div>
  <div class="tile red marda">11</div>
  <div class="tile green marda">12</div>
  <div class="tile blue marda">13</div>
  <div class="tile blue marda">14</div>
  <div class="tile green marda">15</div>
  <div class="tile red toby">16</div>
  <div class="tile yellow toby">17</div>
  <div class="tile yellow marda">18</div>
  <div class="tile yellow">19</div>

</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
  $('a').on('click',function() {
    if($('#menu').css('right')=='0px'){
        $('#menu').animate({right: '-30%'}, 1000);        
    }else{
        $('#menu').animate({right:0}, 1000); 
    }
});
  </script>
```